# Sampling without replacement: probability for total successes from successes in sample?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Consider drawing $n$ balls from an urn containing $N$ balls, of which $m$ are red. If i know $N$, $m$ and $n$ i can use the hypergeometric distribution to calculate the probability that my sample contains exactly $k$ red balls, and using the cumulative distribution i can get the probability to get at most $k$ red balls.

Can i calculate the probability that a total $m$ of all balls are red if i know the number of reds $k$ in my sample? I'm mainly interested in bounding $m$:

$\Pr(m>m_{max}|k=k_{sample})<\epsilon$

My first idea was to use the hypergeometric distribution with $m$ as random variable and norm it so the sum over all $m$ is 1. Is that a valid approach to calculate probabilites and bounds on $m$?

Comment: You have to define a probability space before asking for a probability.  If your purpose is to estimate $m$, you can ask for a confidence interval.

Comment: This is a job for Bayes' theorem.